# Merge two spreadsheets by matching one column

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have an inventory list of items without prices. These items have a reference number in one of the column.

[image: Data sample]

The prices for these items are on *paper* price lists (1 column with reference, 1 column with price).

I want to match each items with its price.

Right now I am doing a search for each reference, then entering the corresponding price, but it is inefficient.

Is there a way to enter the prices manually in another spreadsheet in bulk (one column with references, one column with prices) and then applying some logic to match each duplicate reference with its price?

Maybe there is an even better solution that I didn't think of?

Note: I am using LibreOffice, but I could use Excel if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Maybe an example of your sheets would help.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my spreadsheet. The price list on paper is described in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Once you have your new table of references & prices, a simple [VLOOKUP](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=46746) in either LibreOffice or [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) will cross-match the existing table against the reference/price table to retrieve the current price. The separate reference/price table may be an easier way to maintain current pricing in the future.

Comment: do you think it would work for spreadsheets?

Comment: @pnuts thanks for the OCR suggestion. After looking into it a bit, I think I'll go this way. Only thing now is for me to figure out how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` function search for the first ocurrence of an element in the first row of a matrix, and return the value of one of the columns (defined by parameter).

If I understood correctly your explanation, you can put the PriceList in a sheet, and then:

`=VLOOKUP(<reference_number_cell>, <price_list_interval>, 2, FALSE)`

`<price_list_interval>` represents both columns of the newly created price list (Reference+Price).

This will get the reference number from the whole price list, and get the column 2 (the price) from it. Of course, you need to lock the references for the price list.

`VLOOKUP` function can interpolate from intervals, if your numbers are ordered and he can't find the exact match. Since you're dealing with reference numbers, you shouldn't do it - and that's what that `FALSE` is for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: great, it sounds like what I want! Could you please guide me a little bit though your answer? For example where to put the formula, and which column range should I put in the formula: the one from the inventory, or the newly created price list? Sorry for my ignorance on the matter.

Comment: You put the formula in the cell you want to get the price result, and the range is the newly created price list (the two columns).

Comment: (And, please, don't feel sorry for not knowing something. That's what we all are: not knowing bunch of hormones, willing to fill the gaps... ;) )

Comment: ok, I tried and I get an `err:502`. My function is `=VLOOKUP(Sheet7.A3:A6, Sheet7.B3:B6, 2, 0)`. As you can see I entered the pricelist in sheet7 and I tried on a bunch of references that were the same to try it out.

Comment: ok it works! My formula was wrong. It has to be `=VLOOKUP(A584, Sheet7.A3:B6, 2, 0)`. Thank you!

Comment: @pnuts indeed, thanks for pointing it out. I figured it out eventually though.